# Making a restaurant menu but dots and <sup> aren't working

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, html-lists

I've been making a restaurant website for practice and made the menu using em, strong, and sup tags and it's worked pretty well but it's conflicting with my CSS and / or JQuery and I can't seem to find what part of my code isn't working. The sup tags are acting weird and the dots go through the entire thing.

I've messed with the margin and padding and other tags, even the text-align but I can't seem to find what it is.

```js
//hide all the pages and display the home page
$('.page').hide();
$($('.page')[0]).show();
$($('.page-button')[0]).addClass('selected');

//this block of code switches the pages. it works no matter how many pages or page buttons there are, making it easy to add and remove pages
$('.page-button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.page').hide();
  $($('.page')[parseInt($(this).attr('data-page_num')) - 1]).show(); //displays the page based on the value of data-page_num
  window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll to the  top of the page
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 255);
  font-family: "Open Sans", Sans Serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: ;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
}

.main-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 79px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 0.7s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

a {}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  background: rgb(0, 163, 222);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 105, 242);
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: black;
  decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.content1 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.content2 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.li {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1.8em 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #999;
}

strong {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.3em;
  left: 0;
}

em {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  font: 100% "Times New Roman", Sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.2em;
  right: 0;
}

sup {
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Silver Spoon</h1>
    </li>
    <a class='page-button' data-page_num='1' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
      <li class="main-button home-button">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a class='page-button' data-page_num='2' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
      <li class="main-button about-button">Menu</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div id="Home">
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <a class='page-button' data-page_num='2' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
          <h3>Menu</h3>
        </a>
        <h4>Now introducing edible food.</h4>
        <p>Silver Spoon has a high-quality menu with affordable prices. Find out more on the menu page.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div id="Menu">
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Bakery</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cheese Danish</strong> <em>2</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chocolate Chip Cookies</strong> <em>1</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Glazed Donuts</strong> <em>2</em><sup>00</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Everything Bagels</strong> <em>2</em><sup>00</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Plain Bagels</strong> <em>1</em><sup>50</sup></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Hot Breakfast</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Sandwich</strong> <em>3</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Sausage Sandwich</strong> <em>4</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Bites</strong> <em>4</em><sup>00</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Wraps</strong> <em>4</em><sup>00</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Old-Fashioned Oatmeal</strong> <em>3</em><sup>50</sup></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Sandwiches</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Caprese</strong> <em>4</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Sandwich</strong> <em>4</em><sup>00</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Hamburger</strong> <em>2</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Ham & Swiss Panini</strong> <em>3</em><sup>00</sup></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Deserts</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cookies</strong> <em>1</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cake</strong> <em>3</em><sup>50</sup></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Ice Cream</strong> <em>1</em><sup>99</sup></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this. Group the `sup` and `em` into a `div` and add the following properties:

```
.price {
  position: relative;
  top: .9em;
  float: right;
}
```

Also, you should change this to have `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute` so it is positioned relative to the `li` elements. Then, it should be positioned `.9em` from the top (or 1/2 the padding you added).

```js
//hide all the pages and display the home page
$('.page').hide();
$($('.page')[0]).show();
$($('.page-button')[0]).addClass('selected');

//this block of code switches the pages. it works no matter how many pages or page buttons there are, making it easy to add and remove pages
$('.page-button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.page').hide();
  $($('.page')[parseInt($(this).attr('data-page_num')) - 1]).show(); //displays the page based on the value of data-page_num
  window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll to the  top of the page
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 255);
  font-family: "Open Sans", Sans Serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: ;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
}

.main-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 79px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 0.7s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

a {}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  background: rgb(0, 163, 222);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 105, 242);
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: black;
  decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.content1 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.content2 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.li {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1.8em 0;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #999;
}

strong {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.3em;
  left: 0;
}

em {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  font: 100% "Times New Roman", Sans-serif;
}

sup {
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.price {
  position: relative;
  top: .9em;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Silver Spoon</h1>
    </li>
    <a class='page-button' data-page_num='1' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
      <li class="main-button home-button">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a class='page-button' data-page_num='2' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
      <li class="main-button about-button">Menu</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div id="Home">
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <a class='page-button' data-page_num='2' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
          <h3>Menu</h3>
        </a>
        <h4>Now introducing edible food.</h4>
        <p>Silver Spoon has a high-quality menu with affordable prices. Find out more on the menu page.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div id="Menu">
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Bakery</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cheese Danish</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chocolate Chip Cookies</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Glazed Donuts</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Everything Bagels</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Plain Bagels</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Hot Breakfast</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Sandwich</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Sausage Sandwich</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Bites</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Wraps</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Old-Fashioned Oatmeal</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Sandwiches</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Caprese</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Sandwich</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Hamburger</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Ham & Swiss Panini</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Deserts</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cookies</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cake</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Ice Cream</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>99</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure what result you're expecting from the `border-bottom`, but you can limit the width of the border with a pseudoselector. Remove the border from the `.li` element and add this:

```
.li::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #999;
}
```

Just change the `width` in the pseudoselector to limit how far the border will go.

```js
//hide all the pages and display the home page
$('.page').hide();
$($('.page')[0]).show();
$($('.page-button')[0]).addClass('selected');

//this block of code switches the pages. it works no matter how many pages or page buttons there are, making it easy to add and remove pages
$('.page-button').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  $('.page').hide();
  $($('.page')[parseInt($(this).attr('data-page_num')) - 1]).show(); //displays the page based on the value of data-page_num
  window.scrollTo(0, 0); //scroll to the  top of the page
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgb(204, 204, 255);
  font-family: "Open Sans", Sans Serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: ;
  margin: 0px;
}

ul, li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: left;
}

.main-button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 79px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.main-button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  transition: 0.7s;
  cursor: pointer;
}

h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}

a {}

.container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.button {
  background: rgb(0, 163, 222);
  display: inline-block;
  width: 130px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.button:hover {
  background: rgb(0, 105, 242);
  transition: 0.25s;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: black;
  decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.content1 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}

.content2 {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}

.li {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 0 1.8em 0;
  position: relative;
}

.li::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #999;
}

strong {
  padding: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.3em;
  left: 0;
}

em {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  font: 100% "Times New Roman", Sans-serif;
}

sup {
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.price {
  position: relative;
  top: .9em;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1>Silver Spoon</h1>
    </li>
    <a class='page-button' data-page_num='1' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
      <li class="main-button home-button">Home</li>
    </a>
    <a class='page-button' data-page_num='2' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
      <li class="main-button about-button">Menu</li>
    </a>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div id="Home">
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <a class='page-button' data-page_num='2' href='javascript:voide(0)'>
          <h3>Menu</h3>
        </a>
        <h4>Now introducing edible food.</h4>
        <p>Silver Spoon has a high-quality menu with affordable prices. Find out more on the menu page.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="page">
  <div id="Menu">
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Bakery</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cheese Danish</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chocolate Chip Cookies</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Glazed Donuts</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Everything Bagels</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Plain Bagels</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Hot Breakfast</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Sandwich</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Sausage Sandwich</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Bites</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Egg Wraps</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Old-Fashioned Oatmeal</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content1">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Sandwiches</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Caprese</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Chicken Sandwich</strong><div class="price"><em>4</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Hamburger</strong><div class="price"><em>2</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Ham & Swiss Panini</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>00</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
      <div class="container">
        <h3>Deserts</h3>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cookies</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Cake</strong><div class="price"><em>3</em><sup>50</sup></div></li>
        <li class="li"><strong>Ice Cream</strong><div class="price"><em>1</em><sup>99</sup></div></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note: I've also removed the list bullets using `ul, li { list-style-type: none; }` for readability.

Comment: Thank you, this works great. One thing I'm curious about is the dots, it goes underneath the lists instead of between the list and prices. It's a very minor thing, but how would I fix this to look more presentable?

Answer (score 0):

Do following

**css**

```
.li {
  clear: both;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: dotted 2px #999;
}

strong {
}

em {
  padding: 0 0 0 5px;
  font: 100% "Times New Roman", Sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -.2em;
  right: 0;
}

sup {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 60%;
  color: #666;
  margin-left: 3px;
}
```